# How would I use a setTimeout to run certain things every X amount of times?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have code for a massrole command, to give everyone on a server (excluding bots) a specific role:

```
message.guild.members.filter(m => !m.user.bot).forEach(member => {
   member.addRole(roleNameFind);
   console.log(`[LOG] Gave the role ${roleName} to ${member.user.tag}.`);
});
```

Both "roleNameFind" and "roleName" are defined. But how would I use setTimeout to run both `member.addRole(roleNameFind);` and `` console.log(`[LOG] Gave the role ${roleName} to ${member.user.tag}.`); `` every 5 seconds in the forEach thing?

Comment: Do you mean, delay the forEach logic for each member by 5 seconds?  Or do you literally mean, after 5 seconds, do the exact same logic again for each member?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I mean to delay the forEach for each member by 5 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `setInterval()` not `setTimeout()` for recurring functions.

I also suggest using `client.setTimeout()` and `client.setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` so that the timers can get cleared once the bot stops/restarts.

```js
client.setInterval(() => {
  const member = message.guild.members.filter(m => !m.user.bot).random()
  if (!member.roles.some(role => role.name === roleNameFind)) {
   member.addRole(roleNameFind);
   console.log(`[LOG] Gave the role ${roleName} to ${member.user.tag}.`);
  }
}, 5000)
```

Comment: This just gave everyone the role over and over, just trying to space it out like give 1 member a role every 5 seconds not everyone.

Comment: Then you should be more specific with your question. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I apologize. It also says `':' expected.ts(1005)` at the bottom where the ")" is after the "5000"

Comment: Another quick question, is it also possible to not give members that already have the role, the role? Like skipping over them? Because in my console it's giving the same user that role twice or three times. And also it never stops, it's continuous.

Comment: I added that check in the answer already. `member.roles.some(role => role.name === roleNameFind)`

Comment: Yeah I saw it, and thought it would do that, but it still repeats the person sometimes. At least it repeats the "Gave the role to" message.

Comment: Oh my bad, that's because regardless of whether it actually gave the user the role or not it'd say that since it's not in the `if` statement, I have gone ahead and corrected that mistake.

Comment: Hmm, not sure if it's a mistake with me or not, but I copied that exactly into the command and it's still repeating people. Here's a screenshot, all the members that the log is putting already have the role "Member" https://gyazo.com/b8b9a7277436bf8ce859beabaa7c6885

Answer (score 1):

Use `setInterval`, it does exactly what you want.

```
var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    console.log("This function will be executed each 5 seconds!");
}, 5000);
```

More information of the [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

To stop the interval on the last item, use `clearInterval(intervalId);`

Comment: If explanation could be provided about the downvote, it would be appreciated. I re-read the question and my answer, and I still fail to see how it is unhelpful.

Comment: This answer is about a generalized usage of setInterval.  It doesn't answer the OPs specific question.  If a generalized setInterval usage answer were enough to answer the question, there are bound to be any number of duplicates the question could be voted closed with.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`. You can read the documentation [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp).